How can I loop over an array and store the data in a variable in liquid?
I'm doing the following using JS with liquid:
const variantsWithInventoryData = {};

// Loop through each variant and assign to the object
{% for variant in product.variants %}
  variantsWithInventoryData["{{ variant.id }}"] = {
    inventory_quantity: {{ variant.inventory_quantity }},
    inventory_policy: "{{ variant.inventory_policy }}",
    inventory_management: "{{ variant.inventory_management }}",
    inventory_item_id: 0
  };
{% endfor %}

How can I achieve the above entirely using liquid?
Thanks!

1st I've looped over the variants using only liquid inside a script with a id and then I fetched the required data by parsing the data inside that script element. Here's the implementation:
{% comment %} Separate Liquid Code START {% endcomment %}
<script type="application/json" id="inventory-data">
  {
    {% for variant in product.variants %}
      "{{ variant.id }}": {
        "inventory_quantity": {{ variant.inventory_quantity }},
        "inventory_policy": "{{ variant.inventory_policy }}",
        "inventory_management": "{{ variant.inventory_management }}",
        "inventory_item_id": 0
      }
      {% unless forloop.last %},{% endunless %}
    {% endfor %}
  }
</script>

<script>
  // Fetch the JSON from the script tag
  const inventoryDataFromElement = document.getElementById('inventory-data');
  let varsWithInventoryData;

  varsWithInventoryData = JSON.parse(inventoryDataFromElement.textContent);
  window.varsWithInventoryData = varsWithInventoryData;
  console.log(varsWithInventoryData); 
</script>
{% comment %} Separate Liquid Code END {% endcomment %}

